# Dynamic sorting for a column in a table in power bi

Tags: sorting, dynamic, powerbi

Is there a way in power bi to display top n rows in a table based on varying criterea such as sales amount, expected sales, actual sales, etc. Please look at the picture for better understanding. [image: power bi dynamic top n]

Answer (score 0):

There is `RANK.EQ()` DAX [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492169.aspx) which can return, well, rank of a value in a column.

`SalesRank = RANK.EQ(Table[Sales],Table[Sales])`

Then filter the table visual by `SalesRank <= N`.